# Elixir: Append to a string upto k times

Tags: elixir

IN imperative languages, we can use for loop to append to string upto k times.

```
 str = ""
 k=5
 for i=1 to i=k:
    str = str + "a"
```

Above code will make a string of length k `aaaaa`. Now, we don't have any for/while loops in elixir, and the only way seems to be is the recursion. I wonder if there is any other trivial way of achieving the same. Is something like this possible?

```
In range(1..k)
|> Enum.join(a,"")
```

Comment: There's a [very good example for repeat string problem](https://elixir-examples.github.io/examples/string-repeat-a-number-of-times).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways of achieving this, including list comprehension, but using [String.duplicate/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#duplicate/2) seems like a good choice for that

#### String.duplicate

```
String.duplicate("a", k)
```

#### List Comprehensions

This is probably the most elegant way

```
for _ <- 1..k, do: "a", into: ""
```

#### Mapping and joining a range

```
1..k
|> Enum.map(fn _ -> "a" end) 
|> Enum.join("")
```

#### Stream Module

Useful for parallel computing. Thanks to @mudasobwa

```
Stream.repeatedly(fn -> "a" end)
|> Enum.take(5)
|> Enum.join

Stream.cycle(["a"])
|> Enum.take(5)
|> Enum.join
```

Comment: `Stream.repeatedly(fn -> "a" end) |> Enum.take(5) |> Enum.join` and `Stream.cycle(["a"]) |> Enum.take(5) |> Enum.join`: don’t forget about `Stream` module, it might be _very_ helpful for parallel computing.